# Windows 8 App Javascript: Is applicationData localSettings persistent?

Tags: javascript, windows-8, local-storage

i'm looking for a way to store user Settings in a windows 8 app. I found this storage:

```
applicationData.localSettings["exampleSetting"] = "example";
```

My question is: **Is this data stored in localSettings stored permanently or is it affected by the garbage collector?** First i tried localStorage but this storage gets cleared by the system sometimes and i don't know exactly when. Every attempt to reproduce it fails.

Comment: settings are persisted to disk under appdata folder in a .dat file. you are try this [sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/ApplicationData-sample-fb043eb2/view/SourceCode#content) - folder path will be something like this - C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Packages\<package-id>\Settings\settings.dat

Comment: And do they stay here for the whole time i have installed an app? What happens if there is an update avaliable? Are the settings still there?

Comment: They remain there after update. there is version control also for your app data. if you upgrade the version of your appdata - app get a chance to upgrade its setting/data

Answer (score 1):

This might have to do with versioning of your ApplicationData storage.

http://danielfrost.dk/post/2013/04/15/Saving-stuff-to-RoamingSettings-and-LocalSettings-in-Windows-8.aspx

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone who contributed sth. LocalSettings seem to be persistent until now.